# Xcode 5 setter method: use of undeclared identifier

Tags: objective-c

My `.h` file has

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *usertoken;
```

My `.m` file has

```
@synthesize usertoken;

-(void)setUsertoken:(NSString *)usertoken
{
    _usertoken=usertoken;


}

-(NSString *)usertoken
{

}
```

I am in the process of writing the setters and getters (i.e. they are not done yet). But after writing the line `_usertoken=usertoken`, Xcode is showing an error for `_usertoken`:

```
User of undeclared identifier '_usertoken'; did you mean 'usertoken'?
```

Does anyone know how I might fix this?

Comment: I think that `@synthesize` is unnecessary in Xcode 5. So you can either remove it or try `@synthesize usertoken = _usertoken;`.

Comment: @spassas: `@synthesize` is not unnecessary if you declare both getter and setter yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your use of `@synthesize`.

By simply writing `@synthesize usertoken;`, an ivar is created that is also just called `userToken` (no underscore).

If you instead do `@synthesize usertoken = _userToken;`, it will work correctly.

Comment: The last part of your answer is not correct. If you implement both getter and setter, it will not automatically create an ivar unless you explicitly synthesize one.

Comment: Ah whoops. I actually didn't notice that he did that. Fixing my answer now.